# How to fix jssor slider blurry text issue?

Tags: php, jquery, jssor

I am using jssor slider in my site .

It works fine in every browser except in windows chrome it is showing blurry text.

I already tried setting the `$HWA` option to false.But still blurry text is coming up.

How to fix this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: which place to $HWA option to false use this option in slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely the responsive problem.

If you scale your slider larger than the original size, it may look blurry sometimes.

The way to fix it is to make the original slider bigger with larger elements and font size.
In this manner, it should look better when it scale to smaller size.

Answer (score 0):

```
 To avoid blurry text and remain slider responsive with jssor slider, 
 some   certain change is required in file name called 'jssor.utils.js'.

 In line 1045   transformValue += " perspective(2000px)"; 
 change to 
 transformValue += "none";

   And line 1092  elmt.style[GetTransformProperty(elmt)] =  "perspective(2000px)"; 
  change to 
  elmt.style[GetTransformProperty(elmt)] = "none";
```